# Select statement in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, select, nested

I'm having a problem trying to understand how I would get some data from my sql database.

Lets say I have a database

```
name    worktype    completed 
dave    word        2014-01-01
john    excel       2014-02-07
dave    excel       2014-04-04
dave    access      2014-05-18
dave    word        0000-00-00
john    word        2014-08-25
dave    word        2014-08-13
sue     word        2014-01-10
dave    word        2014-07-21
dave    word        0000-00-00
```

Now I would like to get from this database; (all of the worktypes >= '2014-07-01') + (the worktypes that are "word" and have completed date of "0000-00-00")

```
SELECT worktype FROM workdb1 WHERE worktype = 'word' and completed = '0000-00-00' UNION
SELECT worktype FROM workdb1 WHERE completed >= '2014-07-01;
```

and put the results from that into a second database

```
INSERT INTO workdb2 VALUES(SELECT worktype FROM workdb1 WHERE completed >= '2014-07-01' AND worktype = 'word' AND worktype = ALL AND completed = '0000-00-00'
```

this is basically what I want, but that doesnt work.

is this a subquery? a Join query?

Sorry, pressed "enter" and it submitted before I had finished my question

Thanks

Comment: Hello, don't use reserved words as table names. In this case you are using "database", this is a reserved word in various DBMS.

Comment: I was just using it as a reference to an example database I had shown in the question, I have edited it change the names :) thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use `or` for the two conditions:

```
SELECT worktype
FROM (database)
WHERE (completed >= '2014-07-01') or
      (worktype = 'word' and completed = '0000-00-00');
```

Comment: did not know that it was as easy as that with an "OR" function! Could I use the OR if I was using an INSERT INTO on the same principle?

Comment: @Greylegface . . . If you put an `insert into` statement before this `select`, then you can use `or`.